# How to validate an RSA public key?

Tags: c#, cryptography, rsa

If I receive a PEM-encoded key, I can import it like so:

```
    using var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048);
    rsa.ImportFromPem(keyString.AsSpan());
    // do stuff with it
```

However, [the documentation for `ImportFromPem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsa.importfrompem?view=net-7.0) states that it will indiscriminately accept four key types: PUBLIC KEY, PRIVATE KEY, RSA PRIVATE KEY, RSA PUBLIC KEY, and that "Unsupported or malformed PEM-encoded objects will be ignored."

If I want to verify that 1) what I received is a public key and not a private key, and 2) it's a *valid* public key and not an "Unsupported or malformed PEM-encoded object," how would I go about doing that?

Comment: Check the `KeySize` and `PublicOnly` properties to verify you have imported a valid public key and nothing else

Answer (score 4):

The successful import with the posted code also means a *formal* validation of the RSA key. The key can be imported:

- if it is an RSA key.
- if the key contains one of the labels supported for RSA (i.e. PUBLIC KEY (SPKI), RSA PUBLIC KEY (public PKCS#1), PRIVATE KEY (PKCS#8), RSA PRIVTE KEY (private PKCS#1)).
- if the body consists of a valid (Base64 encoded) ASN.1/DER.
- if the label is consistent with the key contained in the body (both by type (public/private) and format (PKCS#1/PKCS#8/SPKI)).

There is no guarantee that the parameters are validated *contentwise* for consistency (e.g. in the case of a private key, the modulus might well not be equal to the product of p and q). Among other things, this depends on the platform (e.g. Windows or Unix). Thus, if guaranteed validation of the parameters is required, the parameters must be explicitly validated.
Explicit validation of the parameters is possible by exporting the [RSA parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsaparameters?view=net-7.0#summary-of-fields) with `ExportParameters()` and then validating them. This is relevant for private keys, where the parameters are dependent on each other, so that these consistencies can be tested (e.g. whether the modulus is equal to the product of the two primes). There are no such consistency checks for public keys.
Since this question is about public keys, the checks for private keys are not necessary (and could be omitted).

For a key imported this way, [`PublicOnly`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rsacryptoserviceprovider.publiconly?view=net-7.0) can be used to check whether it is a private or public key.

This makes it relatively easy to create a logic for RSA key validation, e.g.:

```cs
using System.Numerics;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
...
private static void ImportPublicKey(string key)
{
    using var rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    try
    {
        rsa.ImportFromPem(key.AsSpan());
        if (rsa.PublicOnly)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Public RSA key");
        }
        else
        {
            // Explicit check of the consistency of the parameters for private keys, for example N = p*q
            var rsaParams = rsa.ExportParameters(true);
            BigInteger m = new BigInteger(rsaParams.Modulus, true, true);
            BigInteger p = new BigInteger(rsaParams.P, true, true);
            BigInteger q = new BigInteger(rsaParams.Q, true, true);
            Console.WriteLine("Private RSA key - params " + (p*q==m ? "consistent" : "not consistent"));
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid or inconsistent RSA key");
    }
}
```

Comment: Here the logic for different valid and invalid keys can be tested online: https://dotnetfiddle.net/nwiGru

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it depends on why you want to validate the public key. You should not expect an adversary to deliberately send a bad key. If they can do that they can simply send you the *wrong* key. To prevent that you need a better way of managing keys, such as using certificates within a Public Key Infrastructure or PKI.

Great, that out of the way, I'd like to indicate that all the defined PEM keys contain a public key. `RSA PUBLIC KEY` is a PKCS#1 defined public key and `RSA PRIVATE KEY` is a PKCS#1 private key. However, the definition of the private key *also contains the public exponent*. Similarly, `PUBLIC KEY` is a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure and `PRIVATE KEY` is a PKCS#8 defined private key. Both *contain* PKCS#1 key structures inside and therefore the public key.

Maybe you suspect that the public key in the instance is not replaced. That is certainly a possible option if I read the documentation correctly (the quality of the Microsoft documentation is often, uh, questionable though). In that case you might want to validate that the modulus changes value. The modulus is specific for each key pair and it is contained in both public and private keys. You can access the modulus  using `ExportParameters(false).Modulus`.

Comment: I don't expect an adversary to deliberately send a bad key; I expect a clueless user to make a mistake.  I've seen people in the past email me a file, "hey Mason, can you install the attached public key?"  The attached file begins `===== RSA PRIVATE KEY =====`.  Much facepalming and careful explaining of the nature of public-key encryption ensued.

Comment: Probably easiest to scan for the word PRIVATE in the header line in that case (it can of course appear in the base64 as well, unlikely, but hey). I don't expect any kind of software to create a public key with a header of a private key, so that's outside the range of user error. Beware that the `PUBLIC KEY` and PRIVATE KEY headers may also contain Elliptic Curve public private keys, but the chances that those are imported as RSA keys is next to zero. By the way, why are you trusting unsigned public keys in the first place?

Comment: ...and that's why I wanted to validate it rather than simply ignore an invalid value.  Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Well, you could have your users also send a signature over some random data that you've send them. If you can verify that signature then you can be 100% sure that it 1. is a valid public key and 2. that it belongs to a private key that they possess (you might want to make sure that they sign the right data of course, supply the software). While you are at it, you might as well have them send an entire Certificate Signing Request, but I don't know what kind of PKI you are trying to set up.